# Duvida sobre extends Application

Tags: android, java-ee

Desenvolvendo para android eu consigo criar uma classe que extende Application. Como eu faria isso em java? Existe isso ou to marcando?

Comment: Você quer estender exatamente a classe Application ou quer apenas estender, de qualquer classe?

Answer (score 5):

Não existe isso em Java, é coisa do Android. No Java você pode até inventar uma classe `Application` para sua aplicação, mas não será como a `android.app.Application` do Android, isto é, não existe uma classe `java.lang.Application` ou `java.app.Application` por exemplo que sirva como template ou base para sua subclasse customizada.

Alguns frameworks podem fornecer uma classe-base semelhante à `Application` do Android para você estender, mas isso seria coisa de um framework específico, para você trabalhar com os recursos do framework, e não uma coisa do Java em si.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, existe isso.

Você pode criar uma classe assim:

```
public class ClasseApplication extends Application{


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //Código a ser executado quando o applicativo é inicializado
    }

}
```

E no seu AndroidManifest.xml, você coloca como attributo da tag  o caminho para a classe.

```
 <application
        android:name="com.pacote.ClasseApplication" >
```

---

Em java é um pouco abstrato, pois existe diversos tipos de apicações em java.
Em jsf por exemplo existe a classe Applcation, que funcionada de uma maneira bem parecida com a do android

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html

Ajudaria se você fosse mais especifico sobre qual tipo de aplicação você quer saber.

Comment: sim, em android eu faço isso, eu queria saber ao contrario, se funcionaria igual ao android

Comment: tipo, em androi para usar extend Application preciso usar import android.app.Application; e em java? import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;??, o que eu quero é iniciar as variaveis globais :)

Comment: Como falei em minha resposta, em Java não existe uma classe padrão para isso, se existir é específica do framework que você estiver usando.

Comment: Eu posso iniciar minhas variáveis globais na classe que estende de Application?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente você deverá criar a classe pai. por exemplo Funcionario.

```
public class funcionario{} //somente um exemplo
```

após devera extende-la ou seja criar uma classe filha para isso usaremos um gerente que é um funcionário.

```
public class gerente extends funcionario{} //exemplo
```

lembrando que na classe filha so devera criar novos métodos o restante é herdado.